# pymongo SONManipulator find_one with few values populated

Tags: python, pymongo

Using [Custom Types in PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/custom_type.html), was able to insert records. My custom object has 5 fields. I need a find_one method which searches based on the fields populated in my custom object. Lets say I create a custom object and populate only 2 fields (unique values though). I need to search MongoDB using this object and manipulator. How do I achieve this? The example mentioned in above link uses find_one() without any argument.

I tried below but it did not return data

```
self.my_collection.find_one({'custom': custom})
#Of course I could specify the complete query. Below fetched the data.
self.my_collection.find_one({'custom.prop1': custom.prop1,'custom.prop2': custom.prop2})
```

As of now I have below work around to achieve the same:

```
def get_one_by_specified_properties(self, custom):
        query_str_map = dict()
        for attr in custom_object_properties_names_as_list():
            if custom.__getattribute__(attr):
                query_str_map.update({'custom.' + attr: custom.__getattribute__(attr)})
        document = self.my_collection.find_one(query_str_map)
        return document['custom'] if document else None
```